# Dax comparison do not support value type text and value type integer

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

i am trying to count from two columns

Column A contains category name i.e. AAT and CCAB

column B contains scores i.e 1,2,3,4 etc

i am trying to count how many people have CCAB (from column A) and score 3 from Column B.

i get an error saying "dax comparison do not support value type text and value type integer"

how can i do this, please

Comment: What does your DAX look like?

Comment: You can achieve this in Transformation layer with 3 or 4 easy steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this measure to get result.

[image]
[image]